# Фиксация позиции в списке после скролла

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, listview, recyclerview

Необходимо сделать так, что после скролла как на картинке_2, отпустив нажатие, список сам перешел в позицию - картинка_3.
И чтоб никогда не было при прокрутки, такого как на картинке_4.

Какие элементы, и какие списки не имеют значения, мне просто нужна реализация, этого эффекта. Любые идеи.

[image: Картинка 1]
[image: Картинка 2]

[image: Картинка 3]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

У RecyclerView, у его LayouManager-ов есть [методы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25053500/3212712):

```
int findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

Засим вы можете сравнивать на равенство результаты индекса первого видимого и первого полностью видимого. В случае их отличия прокручивать список (например, к первому полностью видимому, но не уверен, надо тестировать)

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager )recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
int firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
if(firstVisiblePosition  != firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition )
{
    //надо прокрутить
    //попробуйте что-то типа
    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition );
}
```

Comment: LayoutManager не видит этих методов... Я вначале подумал, что самому их создать надо, а потом полез и увидел их в библиотеке, но мой layout manager их не видит

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, согласно [тык](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29331216/3212712) проблема может быть в неверных импортах классов. Надо пользовать классы из либы поддержки: `android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager`

Comment: да я сразу так подумал и проверил, всё в порядке. ща вот обновляю, SDK мб что изменится. в gradle был v23.1.1. У меня есть идея если использовать эти классы в слушателе и немного своего накидать, ибо существует момент, что человек дернет пальцем и вместо смещения на 1dp он перепрыгнет на целую ячейку, но по этому поводу тоже есть идея. Спасибо за наводку +1, я сразу не увидел.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, у меня эти методы без ошибок работают)

Comment: Я разобрался к сожалению это было очень далеко от правильного ответа, хотя частично помогло.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, тогда опишите своё решение в ответе - наверняка многим будет полезно)

Comment: Я думаю, что мой вопрос вообще некорректен, ибо необходимо решать определенную последовательность задач. Начиная с определения размера ячейка, созданием кастомного адаптера, переопределения нескольких методов, учитывая существующие баги  smoothScrollToPosition, которые добавили ещё несколько задач, переопределения слушателей. тут целая тема. Наверное будет проще удалить вопрос.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Ну, удалять точно не надо. А вот хотя бы кратко описать объём задач с намёками на их решение было бы уместно.

Comment: Да и удалить не разрешили. Я наверное сформулирую ответ, и попробую ответить сам, немного попозже.

Comment: @Shwarz Andrei кстати летом или осенью, вроде, на хабре была статья в тему. Там для ресайулера писали лэйаутмэнэджер с чем то похожим. Вроде еще викпджом элементе пэйджер был

Comment: не встречал, как бы найти её...

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, вот, нашёл: [Рецепты под Android: Как вкусно приготовить LayoutManager](https://habrahabr.ru/company/eastbanctech/blog/267497/)

Comment: Да это прикольно, по сути просто развернутый ViewPager со смещение типа минус margin. Но вот эмулировать его в виде списка будет затруднительно, если элементов будут больше 4. Хотя бы визуально это решило бы эту задачу.
так как активный будет только тот который по центру, а это уже не ок. А смотрелось бы эффективно.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, ну, других идей у меня нема)
Моет, если вы тут конкурс запилите, кто и захочет исследовать проблему более тщательно)

Comment: вот как получилось https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaPMZLIdfR0
вот продолжение https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fSTo4YHlZE

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, круто! Напишите в ответе как запилили? Многим будет интересно)

Comment: там есть один баг, как только его исправлю обязательно напишу в ответ иначе это будет не очень корректно.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, будем ждать)

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei все еще ждем... :)

Comment: Да, сейчас это делается легко)) я дам ответ

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `PagerSnapHelper`.

Этот класс обеспечивает плавную прокрутку таким образом, что каждый элемент списка будет выровнен по центру после завершения прокрутки, как это происходит в ViewPager.

Применить его очень легко:

```
val snapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```

Если у вас нет этого класс убедитесь, что используете свежую версию

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:lastVersion'
```

Answer (score -1):

Определите высоту listView (видимую) разделите на нужное количество строк и присвойте полученную высоту (одной строки) на вновь создаваемый Item в адаптере. А далее

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
```